# checkbox on off is not working on chrome extension?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, checkbox, manifest.json

My default checkbox is checked, when i click the to uncheck it, is not working, just set the button off but is not working and after i close the popup and when i see again the buton is still on so is checked, how i can fix this problem? do i have some error on this script?

**popup.html**

```
<html>
    <head>>

    <link rel='stylesheet' href="css/popup.css"/>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/popup.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div style="padding: 10px;">
    <div style="float:left;"> Players </div>
    <div class="flipswitch">
    <input type="checkbox" name="flipswitch" class="flipswitch-cb cbox" id="fs"  checked>
    <label class="flipswitch-label" for="fs">
        <div class="flipswitch-inner"></div>
        <div class="flipswitch-switch"></div>
    </label>
    </div>
    </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

**popup.js**

```
window.onload = function() {
    if (window.location.href.match('chrome-extension://')) {
        load();
    }
}

$("body").on("change", ".cbox", function() {
    var status = "";
    $(".cbox").each(function() {
        status = status + ($(this).is(":checked")) + ",";
    });

    save_option(status);
});

function save_option(option) {
    var save = {};
    save[option] = null;
    chrome.storage.sync.set({
        option : option
    }, function() {
        console.log(option + "saved");
    });
}

function load() {
    chrome.storage.sync.get(null, function(obj) {
        console.log(obj);
        if (obj.hasOwnProperty("option")) {
            tab = obj.option.split(",");

            console.log(tab);
            var l = 0;
            $(".cbox").each(function() {
                $(".cbox:eq(" + l + ")").attr("checked", parseBoolean(tab[l]));
                l++;
            });
        } else {
        save_option("true");
        }
    });

}

function parseBoolean(str) {
    return /true/i.test(str);
}
```

**manifest.json**

```
"name":"test",
"description":"test",
"version":"1.1.1",
"manifest_version":2,
"icons": { 
    "16": "icons/icon16.png",
    "48": "icons/icon48.png",
    "128": "icons/icon128.png"
},
"browser_action": {
    "default_title": "name",
    "default_popup": "popup.html",
    "default_icon": "icons/icon128.png"
},
"background": {
    "scripts": ["js/background.js"],
    "persistent": true
},
"content_scripts": [
    {
    "js": ["js/content.js", "js/jquery.js"],
    "matches": ["<all_urls>"],
    "run_at": "document_end",

    "all_frames": true  
  }
],
"applications": {
"gecko": {
    "id": "{3b5e61ae-bda1-46c5-89bb-5085cc5ee9c}",
    "strict_min_version": "57.0"
        }
    }, 
"content_security_policy": "script-src 'self'",
"permissions": [
    "webRequestBlocking",
    "unlimitedStorage",
    "webNavigation",
    "<all_urls>",
    "webRequest",
    "activeTab",
    "downloads",
    "topSites",
    "storage",
    "cookies",
    "tabs"
   ]
}
```